# Fetching information from table as object

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there any way to fetch data from SQL Server in Visual Basic like in Javascript in the form of an object from the database server and associative array in PHP

In JS

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 24
}
```

In PHP

```
[
  "id" => 1,
  "name" => "John Doe",
  "age" => 24
]
```

Likewise is there any way to retrieve and manipulate data in visual basic and so that I can print on MsgBox

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Server = DESKTOP-CAKCP8H; Database = info; Integrated Security = True")
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim query = "select * from info"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        /* I want here a variable which contains data like this 
          as in js 
          data = {
            id: 1,
            name: "John Doe",
            age: 24
          }
        so that i can print MsgBox(data.name) => "John Doe"*/
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Since my output will be dynamic so I don't want to use index values

Comment: In SQL 2016 and later, you can return query results as [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server).

Comment: thanks, sir but I am using SQL 2014 and the main thing that how do i work with json in vb

Comment: do you mean vba or vb.net?

Comment: I mean to say vb.net sir

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for JSON library to be used on a VB.NET side. Newtonsoft.JSON? Or perhaps just native .NET entity framework..